# Replace each occurance from a string with a number c#

Tags: c#, string, char, integer

how can I replace each occurrence of a char from a string with a number starting from 0.
e.g

```
aab 
001

tta
001

abba
0110
```

and so on
I m only allowed to use : using system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string input = "abba";
string chars = string.Empty;
string result = string.Empty;

for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
{
    int index = chars.IndexOf(input[i]);

    if (index == -1)
    {
        chars += input[i];
        index = chars.Length - 1;
    }

    result += index.ToString();
}
```